# Load data from Hive to Teradata

Tags: hive, teradata

I want to load data from Hive into Teradata using TeradataExportTool.

-sourcetable 
-targettable

I want to add where condition in hive table to filter only those records to load into teradata.  How to add where condition to select hive data to load into teradata.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to add where conditions.
TeradataExportTool do not execute a select statement. It read the metadata of the table and access directly to the files.